# php mail() function not working with html page

Tags: php, email

In my website I have used mail form which invokes mail_handler.php contains mail function.But its not working and not echoing any output from if-else.
I checked my webmail account its empty for verification. below is my code for form:

```
 <div id="form-main" style="height:500px"; action="mail_handler.php">
 <div id="form-div">
    <form class="form" id="form1">
         <p class="name">
        <input name="name" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" type="text">
         </p>
        <p class="email">
        <input name="email" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" type="text">
         </p>
        <p class="text">
        <textarea name="text" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        </p>
     <div class="submit">
    <input id="button-blue" name="Submit" type="submit">
    <div class="ease"></div>
  </div>
</form>
div>
```

and below is my php code which not taking any values from form but just checking whether php mail function is working or not when form submit button is clicked:

```
  <?php 
  $to = 'yogi@yogeshkorke.com';
  $message='Hii';
  $mail=mail($to, "Subject: $subject",$message );
 if($mail){
 echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
 }
 else{
     echo "Mail sending failed.";  
     }
 ini_set('display_errors',1);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use method post or get in your form
collect in variable
<form class="form" action="mail_handler.php" id="form1" method='post'>
```

Comment: it's not going to work because action is not in form

Comment: I am trying to point out what is missing in user existing form . the method i want to highlight ,rest is understood

Comment: Great. but you need to point this also that action should be in form.And  i am not complaining.